# Как прочитать текстовый файл из буфера обмена?

Tags: python-3.x

Необходимо открыть текстовый файл из  буфера обмена и проанализировать его. Я представляю как можно провести анализ текста, но вообще не представляю как достать файл из буфера. Я искал много чего, но помимо получения текста из буфера ничего нет. Может быть можно хотя бы получить путь скопированного файла?

Comment: А как вы файл копируете, как именно файл? В какой ОС? Или как текст?

Comment: В буфере обмена нет никаких файлов, а только путь к ним.